# oracle query nested select using case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have (2) case statements:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
                   ( SELECT *
                     FROM MYTABLE_A
                     WHERE timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
                   )
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END AS FLAG_MYTABLE_A
from DUAL;
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
                   ( SELECT *, timestamp
                     FROM MYTABLE_B
                     WHERE
                     timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
                   )                       )
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END AS FLAG_MYTABLE_B
from DUAL;
```

RESULTS:

```
FLAG_MYTABLE_A
--------------
             0

FLAG_MYTABLE_B
--------------
         1
```

I need help constructing this query so I can get the following results displayed.

```
MYTABLENAME       MYFLAG
-----------       ------
MYTABLE_A              0
MYTABLE_B              1
```

Am I looking at a nested select? Can someone show me how to set this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'MYTABLE_A' AS MYTABLENAME, CASE WHEN EXISTS
                   ( SELECT *
                     FROM MYTABLE_A
                     WHERE timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
                   )
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END AS FLAG_MYTABLE_A
from DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MYTABLE_B' AS MYTABLENAME, CASE WHEN EXISTS
                   ( SELECT *, timestamp
                     FROM MYTABLE_B
                     WHERE
                     timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
                   )                       )
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END AS FLAG_MYTABLE_B
from DUAL;
```

Comment: A regular `UNION` should be sufficient in this case since there won't be duplicates in the result sets anyway.

Comment: @NWest - Yes, I know, but the `UNION ALL` is faster since it doesn't need to check for duplicates. In this case it might not be important, but I think that is more correct anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT "MYTABLE_A", CASE ... END AS "MYFLAG" FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT "MYTABLE_B", CASE ... END AS "MYFLAG" FROM DUAL
```